# How can i run a diaspora pod through socialvpn?

Tags: linux, webserver, social-networking, vpn, diaspora

I want to route my diaspora social network traffic through a p2p vpn like social vpn.Is socialvpn http://socialvpn.wordpress.com/ good for this job?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like socialvpn will build up a private network without internet access. So if you want to setup a private network with some friends and they all host diaspora, diaspora will be able to exchange data with their nodes. But you need a valid ssl certificate to exchange with other diaspora servers on your private network and you will not be able to exchange with other public diaspora servers on the internet.

Comment: How can i obtain an ssl certificate?If i use a proxy that runs socialvpn can i exchange data with public diaspora servers?thank you

Comment: You need to buy one because diaspora does not work with a self-signed certificate. https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/wiki/SSL-problems